# "push notifications at least one user should be subscribed for APNS" Quickblox

Tags: apple-push-notifications, quickblox

Hi I have an issue here with regards to sending Push Notifications from my app. I can send them from the admin panel and they are received by the device but not from device to device. I have re-uploaded both development and production certificates on a couple of occasions now. Also push notifications can only be sent from the admin panel in the sandbox environment (no errors) and not the production environment (No recipients. At least one user should be subscribed for APNS (Apple Push) (through SDK or REST API). Can someone help please?

//

```
    NSString *message = @"Testing APNS!";
    NSMutableDictionary *payload = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSMutableDictionary *aps = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [aps setObject:@"default" forKey:QBMPushMessageSoundKey];
    [aps setObject:message forKey:QBMPushMessageAlertKey];
    [payload setObject:aps forKey:QBMPushMessageApsKey];

    QBMPushMessage *pushMessage = [[QBMPushMessage alloc] initWithPayload:payload];

    // Send push to user
    [QBMessages TSendPush:pushMessage toUsers:self.opponent.login delegate:self];
```

//

Comment: can you provide your code which sends push notification, please update question

Comment: I've updated my question with the code i'm using. Thanks Igor.

Answer (score 0):

```
 [QBMessages TSendPush:pushMessage toUsers:self.opponent.login delegate:self];
```

You can's send push notification to user's login, you have to use user's ID

For example:

```
 [QBMessages TSendPush:pushMessage toUsers:@"22,33,77" delegate:self];
```

Comment: Thanks Igor I'm now using:
[QBMessages TSendPush:pushMessage toUsers:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self.opponent.ID] delegate:self];

and this works, however, pushDidReceive does not get called. Thanks again for your help here.

Comment: Did you upload correct APNS certificate to Admin panel?

Comment: Yep I uploaded both development and production certificates to the admin panel. I can send push and rich push notifications from the admin panel and I can trigger the audio from the fileID received. Now the push notifications can be sent from the app but I've noticed that pushDidReceive is not getting called. 

- (void( viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector
     (pushDidReceive:)
                                                 name:kPushDidReceive object:nil];
}

Comment: Where do you post notification kPushDidReceive ?

Comment: KPushNotification is set in the viewDidLoad method of ChatView and is implemented in ChatView